# How to call event listener from the function which is in another scope?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, onclick, dom-events

I want to call a Google event listener which looks like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(trucks[data.results[i].id], 'click', function() 
{
// Do the magic :)
}
```

from the function which is not defined in the same scope:

The function is like this:

```
function checkData(){}
```

How can I do that? Can I somehow send the value so it can be the same as the click value? I mean it needs to work on the click event but I want to call it as normal as well.

EDIT:
Let me be more specific:

we have something like:

```
function initialize()
{
google.maps.event.addListener(trucks[data.results[i].id], 'click', function() {};
}
```

and in the different scope we have

```
function checkData()
{
   for (var i = 0; i < window.data.results.length; i++) 
   {
     if(window.data.results[i].driver_id==selectedIndex) 
     {
       // I want to sent the founded object to the event handler in this particular time

     }
   }

}
```

What do I need to put inside the checkData to call it the event handler in the certain time? How do I pass the value to it? Or do I need to pass the value to it?

Comment: Is this even possible what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Is `trucks[data.results[i].id]` a DOM node (a div for example) or a google map object (e.g. a marker)?

Comment: It is a google map object. I need it so I can show it as marker. because when I call that event handler it calls another function and so on. basically I need to find the way to send the object to that event handler so it can be working same as when you click on the marker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised answer:

`google.maps.event` namespace contains a [`trigger`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event) method. You can use this method to *simulate* (for example) click event on an object. You do need a reference to that object.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xRMJM/)

Comment: checkData is defined in global scope and event listener is not

Comment: If it is global then event listener can still access it.

Comment: That's not a problem, JS falls back to the global context. The only issue might be a name conflict: if there is a function with the same name in the scope you're working in, you should make the scope explicit: `window.checkData`

Comment: @denonth: see revised answer; I am not sure if it helps though.

Comment: OMG that's it :) one line of the code and it is working like a charm :) thumb up man

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's pretty easy. Depending on the scope/context where you declared the function:

within the global object: `google.maps.event.addListener(trucks[data.results[i].id], 'click', checkData);`. All this does is pass a reference to the callback. If it's not found in the current scope, JS will refer to the global object.

some other object:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(trucks[data.results[i].id], 'click', function(e)
{
    someObj.checkData.apply(this,[e]);
});
```

In the last case, the event object, e, will be passed as an argument. inside the function `this` will refer to the clicked element/element where the listener was attached.

*Edit*

You're looking for a closure, AFAIK:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(trucks[data.result[i].id],'click',function(e)
{
    //this function will be called on each click, e is the event object:
    checkData.apply(this,[e]);//more arguments? change [e] with: [e,arg2,arg3,...]
});
```

However, if you need to pass arguments that from the local scope, closers start to make even more sense:

```
var insideAfunction ='This string is local';
var anotherOne = {foo:'bar',so:'is this object'};
google.maps.event.addListener(trucks[data.result[i].id],'click',(function(local1,local2)
{
    function(e)
    {
        checkData.apply(this,[e,insideAfunction,anotherOne]);
    }
})(insideAfunction,anotherOne));
```

The event handler, in the last case is an anonymous function, that is the return value of a self-invoking function. This self invoking function received two arguments, local to the current scope. 
 The great thing about closures is, that these variables are linked to the callback function. They're not garbage collected, and as a result the anonymous callback function can access them, or even pass them to the `checkData` function.

Think of closures, the way they're used here at least, as a snapshot of the current scope, its variables and their respective values. Frozen in the state they were in at the time the closure was created. It's a little tricky to get your head 'round at first, but Douglas Crockford has a couple of videos on youtube where he talks about closures. I'd recommend watching them. You'll be amazed at what you can do with closures, and JS in general.

*Update2*

I just read your comment, what you're after (I assume) will look like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(trucks[data.results[i].id],'click',(function(mapObj)
{
    //mapObj === trucks[data.results[i].id]
    function(e)
    {
        checkData.apply(this,[mapObj]);
    }
})(trucks[data.results[i].id]));
```

And now, in the `checkData` function:

```
function checkData()
{
    //your snippet leads me to believe it usually doesn't get arguments passed
    //as a callback, however, we're passing a google map object, access it like so:"
    var passedObject = arguments[0];// === mapObj === trucks[data.results[i].id]
    //safer, even:
    var passedObject = arguments[0] || undefined;
    if (passedObject instanceof Object)
    {
        alert('Called from event');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('called as a regular function');
    }
}
```

Comment: So when I use first option as you said. And I put a`checkData` function as the third argument how do I call that listener from that checkData function in the certain time?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do. checkData will be called when the element you want is clicked (or a child of that element is clicked). The event listener can be accessed, but other than to remove it, I see no reason why you would want to get to the listener itself

Comment: I think I got you a bit of confused. I know it's my fault probably I don't know how to express myself in the right way. What I need is not to change the google maps listener. I just need to call it from the global function and pass the value to it. if that is even possible

Comment: You mean: trigger the event from inside the global function, and get the return value from the handler, and use it in the function `checkData`? Or is my last answer what you needed?

Comment: We are on the good way :) So I just need to pass the object to the event handler from the global function and then I have defined steps in the event handler what I need to do. So we don't need anything to get back to that global function. So `checkData` is only passing values to the event handler and thats it